# WCF Client in C# error 404

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I am learning C# and build a WCF in a web solution, the WCF is just a template ' as is' .

Is a dummy WCF using the visualStudio 2015 templates for an empty WCF, it just does nothing.

If I step in one of my projects (same solution) and 'add service reference' i can see the service and the methods.

I run the application and the webservice is supose to be in http://localhost:61072/Service1.svc

If I go to the URL by hand I got a 404 error (page not found)

If I start a new project and try to add the service reference i got also a 404 error

my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="cadenaConexion" connectionString="SERVER=SQLEXPRESS2008;DATABASE=BD;INTEGRATED SECURITY=TRUE"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure you also running the Service when running the application?

Comment: are you debugging when trying to hit the url?  If not then Visual Studio will not spin up an instance of iis express.  If you do not want to do this then you will need to alter the projects properties to use IIS instead of IIS express, deploy your application and you should be able to hit the given url then.  But the url that you gave tells me that your project is set to use IIS express and will not do anything unless you are running the application in Visual Studio

Comment: Here is a good start to getting your service running in IIS:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396